# Endless loop in dialogflow v2 detectIntent after having split one input query in two queries

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

Per default, Dialogflow can only match one intent per one one input:

*e.g*
`User asks: "How are you?"`
`Dialogflow Agent responds: "I am feeling good!"`
`(Matched intent: intents.howareyou)`

But as soon as the user asks two questions in one input, the agent can not match multiple intents. Only one intent is matched with a smaller confidence interval)
*e.g*
`User asks: "How are you? Do we want to go shopping?"`
`Dialogflow Agent responds: "Yes, lets go shopping!"`
`(Matched intent: intents.shopping)`

There are two options now to enable the agent to answer both questions in one input:

- Create an intent and let the agent response exactly for these two questions.
  => This is a very bad solution, as soon as you add more possible questions/intents. Then you would need to create every combination of every question.
- Split the one input into several queries and let the agent perform the intent matching again on the splitted query.
  => This is the preferred way

Based on some blogs in the internet (e.g. https://docs.meya.ai/docs/handle-multiple-intents-in) the second option is what I did.

The Default Fallback Intent is set to use the Fulfillment webhook and this a small part of code executed:

```
function parseMultipleIntents (agent) {
const query = agent.query;
var pattern= /(.+?[!.?]+)/gm;
var match = pattern.exec(query);

 while (match !== null) {
  console.log(match[0]);
  handleQuery(match[0]);  //<----
  match = pattern.exec(query);
 }
}
```

The `handleQuery` method is the actual method, where the splitted queries are handled:

```
function handleQuery(query){
    console.log(query);
    // The path to identify the agent that owns the created intent.
    const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath("PROJECT_ID", "FIXED_SESSION_ID");

      const request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
          text: {
            text: query,
            languageCode: 'de',
          },
        },
      };

    sessionClient
      .detectIntent(request)
       .then(responses => {
                console.log('Detected intent');
                const result = responses[0].queryResult;
                console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
                console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
                if (result.intent) {
                  console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
                } else {
                  console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
                }
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.error('ERROR:', err);
              });
}
```

The problem:
If I comment everything in the handleQuery method except `console.log(query);` then the console outpuut in the firebase console looks fine:

`originalQuery: und?warum?`
`11:39:58.240 PM dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment warum?`
`11:39:58.238 PM dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment und?`

But as soon as I uncomment the rest of the handleQuery and the code looks like above, I get the following console messages which is not stopping. The messages go one if I scoll up in the console. It seems like some kind of loop:

[image]

-

[image]

-

[image]

Do I use detectIntent correctly or do you had such experiences? Or can you spot an issue? 
I presumed issues with sync/async calls and also added Promises, but the same happened...

Thanks